# Not able to print console message synchronously using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am updating array of record into my database and after each update I am printing some messages but here the issue is all the success/error messages are printing at a time after all record update. I am explaining my code below.

```
const updateRecord = async (records, connObj) => {
  try{
    const isExistKey = records.some(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(config.collectionKey));
    let collKey = config.collectionKey;
    console.log('collection key=========> ', isExistKey);
    if(isExistKey) {
      let updateCount = 1;
      for(let obj of records) {
        if(obj[collKey] && obj[collKey] === '') {
          console.log(`The search key value is missing for row ${updateCount} from the sheet.`);
        }else{
          let serchKeyVal = obj[collKey];
          let filter = {
            [collKey]: obj[collKey]
          }
          delete obj[collKey];
          let flag = Object.values(obj).every((v) => v !== '');
          if(!flag) {
            console.log(`Some of the values are missing for row ${updateCount} from sheet. So could not update.`);
          }else{
            const upObj = obj;
            console.log('filter & up===> ', filter, upObj, serchKeyVal);
            await connObj.collection(config.mongoCollection).updateOne(filter, { $set: upObj }, function (err, data) {
              if(err) {
                console.log(`Record could not updated with for ${serchKeyVal}`);
                console.log('Error while updating record====> ', err);
              }else{
                if(data.result.nModified === 1) {
                  console.log(`Record updated successfully for ${serchKeyVal}`);
                }else{
                  console.log(`No matched record/No new value to update for ${serchKeyVal}`);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
        updateCount++;
      }
    }else{
      console.log('The collection key is not found in csv sheet.');
    }
  }catch(error) {
    console.log('Error while updating records ===> ', error);
  }
}
```

Here inside array I am taking each object and updating after some validation. Here `console.log('filter & up===> ', filter, upObj, serchKeyVal);` is printing after each iteration of record and supposed to update the same record and print the update status. But issue is all the success/error messages are printing at a time after database work is finished where I need as per the loop iteration the database response should be printed. If somebody can suggest some workaround will be great help.